# My iPod has fallen out with iTunes. What's the safest way to get them back on speaking terms?

Tags: itunes, ipod, backup

My girlfriend moved her iTunes library into [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) and now her iPod Touch doesn't recognise it. I moved it back to where it had been before, but this wasn't enough to get it to sync without threatening to erase everything.

I'm planning on using iTunes to [back up](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766) the iPod, copying the back-up file to somewhere safe, then syncing. I hope that I can then restore any lost notes etc.

Firstly, will this work? Secondly, I think that the music she's bought recently through the device won't be backed up. How can I retrieve that?

The OS is Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it should work.
2. All music she has bought is under Purchased in Quick Links menu in iTunes Store in latest iTunes. It can be redownloaded from there.

Comment: This seems to have worked. Looks like I didn't need to deal with the purchased aspect - maybe she hasn't bought anything since the problem started. Thanks for your help.